# TDD: Do I have to define everything my code should NOT do?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, tdd

**Problem**

I'm using Test-Driven Development and having trouble making my tests define my code well enough. A simple example of my problem is as follows.

I have `MyObject` from which I want to call either `methodA()` or `methodB()` belonging to `OtherObject` depending on what argument `MyObject` receives in its own `callMethod(int)`.

**Anticipated code (and desired functionality)**

This is essentially what I want the code to do - but I want to do it test first:

```
public class MyObject {

    private final OtherObject otherObject;

    public MyObject(OtherObject otherObject) {
        this.otherObject = otherObject;
    }

    public void callMethod(int i) {
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            otherObject.methodA();
            break;
        case 1:
            otherObject.methodB();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

**Writing it test first**

To achieve this I start by writing a test - check that `methodA()` is called when calling `callMethod(0)`. I use JUnit and Mockito.

```
public class MyObjectTest {

    private final OtherObject mockOtherObject = mock(OtherObject.class);
    private final MyObject myObject = new MyObject(mockOtherObject);

    @Test
    public void callsMethodA_WhenArgumentIs0() {
        myObject.callMethod(0);
        verify(mockOtherObject).methodA();
    }
}
```

I create the classes/methods needed to get rid of errors and make the test pass by implementing `MyObject`'s method like this:

```
public void callMethod(int i) {
    otherObject.methodA();
}
```

Next a test for the other option - calling `callMethod(1)`

```
@Test
public void callsMethodB_WhenArgumentIs1() {
    myObject.callMethod(1);
    verify(mockOtherObject).methodB();
}
```

And I get a final solution of:

```
public void callMethod(int i) {
    otherObject.methodA();
    otherObject.methodB();
}
```

**The issue**

This works but is clearly not what I want. How do I progress to the code I want using tests? Here I have tested for the behaviour I would like. The only solution I can think of is to write some more tests for behaviour I would *not* like to see.

In this example it would be okay to write 2 more tests to check that the other method is not being called but surely doing it like that is more of an issue in the general case. When there are more options, more complexity in which methods and how many different methods are called depending on the circumstances.

Say there were 3 methods in my example - would I have to write 3 tests to check the right method is called - then 6 more if I'm checking the 2 other methods aren't called for each of the 3 cases? (Whether you try and stick with one assertion per test or not you still have to write them all.)

It looks like the number of tests will be factorial to how many options the code has.

Another option is to just write the `if` or `switch` statements but techically it wouldn't have been driven by the tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regard to your specific example, I'd say you are doing it exactly right.  Your tests should specify the behavior of your class under test.  If you need to specify that your class doesn't do something under some circumstance, so be it.  In a different example, this would not bother you.  For instance, checking both conditions in this method probably would not raise any objections:

```
public void save(){
  if(isDirty)
     persistence.write(this);
}
```

In the general case, you are right again.  Adding complexity to a method makes TDD harder.  The unexpected result is that this is one of the greatest ***benefits*** of TDD.  If your tests are hide to write, then your code is also too complex.  It will be hard to reason about and hard to maintain.  If you listen to your tests, you'll consider changing your design in a way that simplifies the tests.

In your example, I might leave it alone (it's pretty simple as is).  But, if the number of `case` grows, I'd consider a change like this:

```
public class MyObject {

    private final OtherObjectFactory factory;

    public MyObject(OtherObjectFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    public void callMethod(int i) {
        factory.createOtherObject(i).doSomething();
    }
}

public abstract class OtherObject{
    public abstract void doSomething();
}

public class OtherObjectFactory {
    public OtherObject createOtherObject(int i){
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            return new MethodAImpl();
        case 1:
            return new MethodBImpl();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this change adds some overhead to the problem you are trying to solve; I would not bother with it for two cases.  But as cases grow, this scales very nicely: you add a new test for `OtherObjectFactory` and a new implementation of `OtherObject`.  You never change `MyObject`, or it's tests; it only has one simple test.  It's also not the only way to make the tests simpler, it's just the first thing that occurred to me.

The overall point is that if your tests are complex, it doesn't mean testing isn't effective.  Good tests and good design are two sides of the same coin.  Tests need to bite off small chunks of a problem at a time to be effective, just like code needs to solve small chunks of a problem at a time to be maintainable and cohesive.  Two hands wash each other.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to take a slightly bigger-picture view of your code.  Don't think about what methods it should call, but think about what the overall effect of those methods should be.

- What should the outputs and the side-effects be of calling `callMethod(0)`?
- What should the outputs and the side-effects be of calling `callMethod(1)`?

And don't answer in terms of calls to `methodA` or `methodB`, but in terms of what can be seen from outside.  What (if anything) should be returned from `callMethod`?  What additional behaviour can the caller of `callMethod` see?

If `methodA` does something special that the caller of `callMethod` can observe, then include it in your test.  If it's important to observe that behaviour when `callMethod(0)` happens, then test for it.  And if it's important NOT to observe that behaviour when `callMethod(1)` happens, then test for *that* too.

Answer (score 1):

Great question. Applying TDD to the letter (especially using the Devil's Advocate technique as you did) reveals some interesting problems indeed.

Mark Seemann has a [recent article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/10/23/mocks-for-commands-stubs-for-queries/) about a similar issue where he proves that using a different, slightly more strict kind of mock solves the problem. I don't know if Mockito can do that but with frameworks such as Moq, making `mockOtherObject` a strict mock would in your example result in the exception we want, because a call to the non-prepared method `methodB()` would be made.

That being said, this still sorts of falls into "testing what your code shouldn't do" and I'm not a big fan of verifying that things don't happen - it rigidifies your tests a lot. The only exception I see is if a method is critical/dangerous enough to your system to justify using defensive means to ensure it isn't called, but this shouldn't happen often.

Now, something might trump the whole conundrum - the Refactor part of the TDD cycle.

During that step, you should realize the `switch` statement smells a bit. How about a more modular, decoupled way ? If we think about it, the action to be taken in `callMethod()` is really decided by

- `MyObject`'s instantiator (which passes the appropriate `OtherObject` upon construction)
- `callMethod()`'s caller (which passes the appropriate `i` parameter from which will depend the method call)

So an alternative solution could be to somehow combine the passed `i` with one method in the object that was injected at construction to trigger the expected action (@tallseth 's Factory example is exactly about that).

If you do this, `OtherObject` doesn't have to have 2 methods any more - the `switch` statement and the Devil's Advocate bug disappear altogether.